# Remove a moving object from a video

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I have a video of a ball bouncing and I need to remove the ball from the video.
 If I have a template of the ball, is there anyway I can remove the moving ball from the video frames?
I'm new to opencv so a bit confused as to how to go about it.

Comment: What happens with the part of the image that was removed? Does it stays black?

Comment: No it takes on the background.

Comment: The way I see things, when you remove pixels (ball) from an image, the area that was removed becomes a single color region. So the question is, what color do you want it to be?

Comment: Umm no you can do it finding the running average. Working on it at the moment Ill post it as an answer once im through

Comment: That's exactly the point I wanted to make. You didn't make it clear what should happen to the image once the object is removed. Now we know! ;) You should add that to the question.

Comment: did you crack this one nette? If so could you post your answer please. Has the video got the same background through out the video ? Ie is it only the ball moving . If so then I believe you should be able to average the individual pixels between frames and build a new video with the ball moved. I think it would possibly be easier if it was a series of snap shots rather then video but I'm no expert on OpenCV .   Ah I've just realised how old this post is. Still I'll leave my comment as I was looking for something similar and hope Nette will have an example.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem statement you know(have) the template of the ball! Because the shape of the ball is invariant to rotation and translation you can use template matching. If you are not familiar with template matching see [this tutorial for opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). After you found the ball now you need to remove it using [inpainting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting). A tutorial exits for opencv in [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html). All the steps have to be done for each frame.

Another way to do inpainting is to use MRFs for inpainting. see [this page](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~komod/research/index.html) for docs.

Good Luck!